# placing the shape in front of the image in c#

Tags: c#, shapes

i have one picture showing of the human body and i want to use shapes to locate the injuries of the patient. all the shapes will shows off when the user click button. right now im testing with only one shape.

here is my code.

```
private void button7_Click_4(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(this.BackColor);

        Image img = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\humanbody\\effect2.png");
        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Height, img.Width);
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

right now, the shape appear at the back of the image. so how i want to make the shape appear in front of the picture?

[image]

Comment: I think you might be drawing the shapes first, then the image. Can you show us the code that you are using to draw the shapes?

Answer (score 4):

Couple of issues.

1) Painting should happen in a paint event.  Do not use CreateGraphics since that will only be a temporary drawing.

2) Your DrawImage width and height arguments are reversed.

3) It doesn't look like you are painting the PictureBox control that you have on the form:

```
private Image img;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  button1.Click += button1_Click;
  pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  img = = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\humanbody\\effect2.png");
  pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);

  if (img != null) {
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);

    //Draw test shape:
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 60));
  }
}
```

Comment: i copy paste your code into mine. it still appear the shape at the back of the picture..do i make mistake here??

Comment: @sarabrown If it doesn't work, then you have code running that we cannot see.  One thing that stands out is your code seems to be drawing on the form itself, where you have obviously buttons, too.  Generally, you should have a Panel or a PictureBox control where this image should be displayed.

Comment: im using component from the toolbox which i only drag any component to the place i wish to use. the picture is from the picture box and is put inside in the panel. i also edit my post for a better view. hope it helps.

Comment: sorry. my internet suddenly slows down and i thought i already click the submit button. i hope the picture would give the clear view.

Comment: @sarabrown I updated my example.  The painting needs to happen on the PictureBox control, not on the form, which is what your code was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first get graphics of human image and then draw shape image on it. Some thing like that :

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\humanbody\\effect2.png"); 

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage ( img );

g.DrawImage(ShapeImage, 0, 0, 30, 30); // you can set your required x,y,width,height
```

Comment: it wont work as well.it appears at the back of the picture. do u have any other solution or perhaps im doing it in a wrong way?